# "Prejudice" in a positive sentence

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I found some websites use "prejudice" to describe their selling points.

- [sushi restaurant](http://www.shin-hinata.com/bangkok/prejudice.html)
- [tea store](https://www.uji-en.co.jp/products/list.php?category_id=36)
- [industrial company](https://www.ishimok.co.jp/english/about/prejudice.html) - Not in content but in URL

Can I use prejudice for such positive stuff?  Or is it just a fault caused by machine translation?

FYI: The equivalent (at least they think so) word in Japanese is "こだわり" (kodawari) and it means some points that one believes it cannot be omitted.  The term can be used in both positive and negative sentences.
Only Google translation associates こだわり with prejudice.  I could not find any dictionaries do so.

Comment: Looks like a case of bad jp->en translation to me.

Comment: jisho.org gives "speciality" for こだわり in the context of restoraunts, but google translate gives "prejudice", "hitch" and "trouble".Guess we know what they used...

Comment: Can you give actual examples in your question? (However, not that people can be prejudiced *in favour* of something just as easily as *against* it.)

Comment: From the tea store page you linked: `Writing "male" of "fire" and reading "fire man", I have always been managing firewood as a man who always cooked as a cooked man, so Illustrated also as a gesture to breathe in firewood I am doing it. ` - it really looks like a very bad machine translation.

Comment: Thank you for comments!  As you pointed, it seems to be caused by Google translation.  So, "prejudice" has only negative meanings?